# How to redirect with ng-route when I encounter a specific hash

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm trying to do this with my app:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/faq', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/faq.html',
    title: 'Faq'
}).
when('/faq#item-1', {
    redirectTo: '/faq'
)
```

Is this possible ?

What I'm trying to do is redirect only the urls that include `#item-1` to the default route while leaving for example thos with `#item-2` to work as normal.

Comment: The routing provider refers to the hash value only. So `/faq` matches URLs such as `something/#/faq`. It's basically watching a value similar to that returned by `$location.path()` or `location.hash`.

Comment: @Boaz so you're saying what I want to do is impossible, sigh could you add it as an answer and I'll accept it.